# How to build .apk & .ipa in Flutter, using Android Studio?

Tags: android, ios, apk, flutter, ipa

I am new to *`Flutter` developement*.
I kept reading, understanding & following [Flutter Documentation](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/#step-1-create-the-starting-flutter-app) and has created my first flutter app **in Android Studio IDE**. It is working fine in android emulators.

Now I want to test application in iOS simulator but I don't know how to generate build for iOS.

Is it possible to generate .ipa through Android Studio IDE? If yes then how can I do that? Also I can not build .apk, what are the steps for that?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: AS should list emulators and connected devices. If you select on and debug-run the apo should be started on the selected emulator. You can also use `flutter run` on the command line or `flutter build apk --release` `flutter install`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am working on linux os, `flutter build apk --release` This command works perfect & gave me release build for Android. Thanks...

Comment: But when I am trying to run `flutter build ios --release` on terminal I receive an error saying `Building for iOS is only supported on the Mac.` Is there any work around to run on linux!? @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

```
flutter build apk --release 
flutter install
```

To build for iOS you need a Mac, because it depends on XCode to compile parts of the application.

Comment: Hi, where can we locate debug build of ios (is it .ipa?), I want ios file on the lines of .apk to share it to client and testers. Tried and tired of no answers online, thank you!

Comment: Do we need a physical ios device to generate .ipa or is simulator enough?

Comment: You need a Mac with Xcode, but no device or emulator

Comment: I have mac on virtual machine Virtual Box with Xcode and could run code on Simulator but where can I find build file for ios that I can send to testers. Thank you.

Comment: `flutter build ios` and then look in the `build/` directory

Comment: I found Runner.app folder in build/ios/iphonesimulator/ ... help me on how to install this on iphone5.

Answer (score 0):

You should first install **X-Code** and **Android Studio** (with Flutter settings and **SDK** enabled) on macOs, then copy your source code there and open with Android Studio.

After that run `flutter clean`, `flutter packages get` and `flutter build ios` commands in order.

If you have used some libraries that are not supported in **iOS** they must be omitted or replaced in the project (it can be determined by seeing the library's official page on **pub.dev**).

Then connect the iPhone to mac and if everything is OK it should be visible in device list section, finally press the Run button to finalize required dependencies by downloading from the internet.